# Firefox Only :Multiple controls with the same ID 'FContent<GUID>' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs

Tags: sitecore-client

After migrating to Sitecore 9.3 from 8.2, we are getting "Multiple controls with the same ID 'FContent' were found. FindControl requires that controls have unique IDs" popup on clicking any item type in the Content Tree and its happening only in Firefox browser.

Have tried below solution but it didn't help: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/384386

[image]

Comment: make sure you don't have any old dlls references.

Comment: I have this problem too on Sitecore 9.02 Update 2. I'm using a self-signed certificate and this problem appears when using "https" on Firefox. If I just use "http", the problem disappears. Don't know if that might help you. Did you manage to get to the bottom of it? Thanks Edit - also, seems to affect Firefox 82.0, but **not** Chrome 86.0.4240.198

Comment: Did you resolve this?